# Visualizing a matrix in python seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

There is some data I'm having trouble with visualizing properly.
The concept is as follow:
lets say there are 20 countries and 30 people.
Each person should rate each country (between 0-100).
so we have a matrix 20X30 which each enrty represents the rates of the corresponding person&country.
What sort of plot do you think would best present that kind of data? (I'm using python. So, a function in seaborn/matplotlib would be the best)
Note: the most important thing is that there are two types of countries:

1. Countries that are rated very high by only 1/2 people and rated low by the others, and it should be noticeable directly which people rated those countries high.
2. Countries that are rated medium by 10+ people.

BTW, I found this figure on the coronavirus statistics site which is not perfectly fitting but it is something I might want to use. I would like to know if there's a function for this kind of plot in seaborn/matplotlib. Thank you!! :)
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).